# Angular 2 and C# API - Unhandled Promise rejection: ReferenceError: _body is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have a working API written in C# that return something like this:

```
        status: 200, 
        ok: true, 
        statusText: "OK", 
        url: "http://localhost:53619/api/EventList/All"
        _body: "[
            {
            "id":"6eb057be-1c27-4d92-83cc-95216dc1b21b",
            "user":{"id":"mail@mail.org",
            "firstname":"name",
            "lastname":"lastname",
            "email":"mail@mail.com",
            "avatar_url":"string"},
            "project":
                {   "id":0,
                    "name":"super project",
                    "description":"woop woop",
                    "created":"2016-09-15T10:09:17.425Z",
                    "autodesk_client_id":"123456",
                    "autodesk_client_secret":"123"},
                    "title":"Jan lagde et super prosjekt",
                    "content":"test",
                    "icon":"string",
                    "type":"string",
                    "properties":"string",
                    "datetime":"2016-09-15T12:16:56.6826078+02:00"}
            ]
```

This is the default response from the C# API. HTTP status code, url, message etc. Then there is a variable _body containing the json data I actually need.

Then in Angular 2 I have the following to get the data:

```
  get(data: User): Promise<Event[]> {

    let body = JSON.stringify(data);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http
      .post(this.apiUrl + '/All', body, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res._body.json();  <--------- ERROR (_body not defined)
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

This works well, I get all the data and it's printed out in the console. 
But Angular refuse to accept that the Response contain the variable _body and crash!

How can I fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use **return res.json()._body;**